# TornadoFX dependency injection

Tags: dependency-injection, tornadofx

Is there a simple TornadoFX-specific way of injecting something other than a component or controller (for example, a service class)?

The docs only mention using `inject()` for `View` and `Controller` classes. 
Is it best to integrate Guice or Spring for injecting anything other than these two classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In TornadoFX, you'd put your business logic in either a `Controller` or a `ViewModel`. The TornadoFX `Controller` might be a slight misnomer in that way - it is actually primarily meant for business logic, not controlling the View. A `View` on the other hand, normally acts as the controller for the UI elements, connecting event handlers to actions in a `Controller`.

There is normally no need to use Guice or Spring, unless you are converting an application that already utilize a dependency injection framework and you don't want to rewrite those parts.

For completeness, the guide includes information about how to integrate with 3rd party injection frameworks:

https://edvin.gitbooks.io/tornadofx-guide/content/part2/Dependency%20Injection.html